# Space inserted after using a macro defined with DeclareMathOperator

Tags: math-mode, macros, spacing, amsmath, math-operators

I am trying to learn how to make macros in LaTeX on overleaf, and I am trying to make a simple macro for \mathrm{d}, however when I use the macro a space is inserted after it.

The macro definition is as follows:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\deriv}{\mathrm{d}}
```

And the code that I am using to test it is as follows:

```
\[ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \]
\[ \frac{\deriv y}{\deriv x} \]
```

And the output that I am getting:

[image: LaTeX output]

Comment: That's a recurring question `:-)`. The common lore is to do `\newcommand*{\deriv}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Well, that's exactly what `DeclareMathOperator` is supposed to do:) this command is used to define operators like e.g. `rk` for the rank of a matrix, where you want to have a little space behind it. You are probably looking for `\newcommand{\deriv}[0]{\mathrm{d}}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! That is normal. Just like when you code `\cos x`, you have a small spacing between the name of the function and its argument. This being said, you have two packages that makr typing derivatives in Leibniz' notation quite easy: `esdiff` and `diffcoeff`. Do you really have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Bernard did not know of `diffcoeff`... how did I manage without? Thanks!